# Undefined property: stdClass::$return

Tags: php, arrays, soap

For those who have knowledge with cyclos 3.7.3, I'm trying to get the webshop payment work but I could find the error and all I get is error generating ticket, I tried to print the ticket then I got Undefined property:

> stdClass::$return in line C:\xampp\htdocs\cyclos_ws\prepare_payment.php on line 29.

This is the code I use.
Thanks for help.

```
<?php
// Get the web service proxy
require_once 'cyclos.php';
$cyclos = new Cyclos();
$webShopService = $cyclos->service('webshop');

    if (isset($_POST['user'])) {

    $user = $_POST['user'];
    $description = $_POST['description'];
    $amount = $_POST['amount'];
    $adsip = $_POST['adsip'];
}

// Setup the payment parameters
$params = new stdclass();
$params->amount = $amount;
$params->description = '$description';
$params->clientAddress = '$adsip';
$params->toUsername = '$user';

// This should be the absolute url for the page which will process the payment
$params->returnUrl = "http://localhost/cyclos_ws/complete_payment.php";

// Generate the ticket
try {
    //Ensure the input parameter is named 'params' and the output, 'return'
    $ticket = $webShopService->generate(array('params' => $params))->return; //line 29
} catch (SoapFault $e) {
    die("Error generating a payment ticket: $e");
}
print_r($ticket);

// With the ticket ok, redirect the client to perform the payment
//header( "Location: ".Cyclos::$server_root."/do/webshop/payment?ticket=".$ticket ) ;
?>
```

Comment: Maybe you're missing something in your code. Check out the documentation. https://www.cyclos.org/wiki/index.php?title=Web_services/WebShop_payment

Comment: i've checked and recheked, but nothing is missing

Comment: Did you try inspecting the result of $webShopService->generate(array('params' => $params)) using var_dump()?  It could be the 'return' variable is not at the root of the object.

Comment: @KrisPeeling how i can do that? can you explane for me pls

Comment: Try $result = $webShopService->generate(array('params' => $params)); followed by var_dump($result);exit; You should see the contents of the $result variable - It will be a stdClass and show you all the properties.

Answer (score 0):

You have used variables within single quotes. It should be wrapped within double quotes.

PHP doesn't parse single quotes, therefore, variables within single quotes will be ignored. For instance:

```
$var = 'String';
echo 'This is a $var'; // Output: This is a $var

$var = 'String';
echo "$var"; // Output: This is a String
```

Variables inside double quotes will be parsed in PHP to check and process them.

Whenever you use variables inside quotes, wrap them with double quotes.

Comment: what if i use static instead of variable
example:
$params = new stdclass();
$params->amount = 23;
$params->description = 'test';
$params->clientAddress = '192.168.x.x';
$params->toUsername = 'user';
is it correct??

Comment: You have passed literal values, so it will work. You could pass variables alone without any quotes like `$params->description = $description`. You can do this way if you're going to use only variables.

Comment: Oh. Maybe you should refer to a documentation more precisely.